# How to add an object as a field to another existing object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and I am trying to do a basic operation on a JS object.

I have the following object:

```
var originalObj = {
   id: 1,
   name: 'originalObj'
}
```

Now I would like to add another object as a field to `originalObj`.

```
var newObj = {
   newId: 2,
   name: 'newObj'
}
```

So expected outcome is:

```
orginalObj = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'originalObj',
  newObj: {
    newId: 2,
    name: 'newObj'
  }
}
```

What I tried so far:

1. `originalObj.newObj = newObj`  and `originalObj['newObj'] = newObj`

This results in:

```
orginalObj = {
      id: 1,
      name: 'originalObj',
      newObj: 
    }
```

2. `Object.assign(originalObj, newObj)`
   This add all the fields of `newObj` on the same level as `originalObj`. Like below:

   originalObj = {
         id: 1,
         name: 'originalObj',
         newId: 2,
         name: 'newObj'
     }

Comment: `Object.assign(originalObj, {newObj})`

Comment: What is the difference between expected output and what you get from the first attempt?

Comment: @adiga I fixed my question sorry.

Comment: First attempt will give the proper output.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on if you want a deep copy or just a reference.

`originalObj.newObj = newObj;` will assign a reference to newObj where as

`originalObj.newObj = Object.assign({}, newObj);` will create a new one.

Note: if your using ECMAScript 2015 (6th Edition, ECMA-262) you can use the spread operator `...`

`originalObj.newObj = {...newObj};`

Example: https://jsbin.com/yisiyip/edit?js,console

Answer (score 0):

```
const originalObj = {
   id: 1,
   name: 'originalObj'
}

const newObj = {
   newId: 2,
   name: 'newObj'
}

originalObj  = { ...originalObj, newObj }
```

what's happening here is you are spreading the values of originalObj into an empty object together with the value of newObj by shorthand method

reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Comment: Please explain answer in deatails to understand to others more effectively.

Answer (score 0):

originalObj.newObj=newObj; //this should do the job

[image: in console it looks like this]